# Filter lookup column based on another field value

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, filter

Scenario: I have Tasks list with a (lookup) column Project. I have also a multivalue lookup column Predecessors pointing to the Tasks list itself.

Question: Is it possible to filter available Tasks based on the Project column value to show only the Task having same project? Is it possible to get it done without coding?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without a little JavaScript coding.. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is fine. I meant a server code.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, multivalue lookup column is not filtered, it is just displayed?

Comment: No; the multivalue lookup column is filtered based on value of another column.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to populate a drop-down fetching projects from the Projects list and than on selection redirect to the same page with ProjectId (ID) in the Query String..

Use List View Web Part to get the ProjectId from the Query String (as Query String Parameter) and filter the tasks list.

Following blog post should help (It is using External List so ignore the External Content Type and Filters etc.) but configuring the List View Web Part and JavaScript to redirect with Query String will help

[External List with BCS & Search Filters](https://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/)

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally missing the point of your question, but it looks like a plain filtered, no-code *view filtered by lookup column* would solve your problem.

When browsing the Task list, create a new view. In view settings scroll down to filter area. Select your lookup column from the dropdown list and entered desired filtering value.

Comment: Have you considered that the filtering value is not a constant but it changes as a user fills the form?

Comment: Ok. What about view with group by lookup column?